# Преобразрвание типа char в методе System.out.println()

Tags: char, java

Добрый день. Помогите, пожалуйста, разобраться в проблеме. Я только начал изучать программирование и очень много подводных камней, которые хочу понять. Есть код :

```
   System.out.println('b');
   System.out.println('b' + 'c');
   System.out.println((char)('a' + 4));
```

И задан вопрос: что выведет этот фрагмент кода? Я не понял что он выведет и написал и скомпилировал код:

```
b
197
e
```

И у меня появились вопросы :

1. Почему результат вывелся , если
       мы    даже нигде не объявили и не 
       инициализировали , не присвоили тип 
       этим переменным a , b , c ?
2. Почему во втором результате
       получилась цифра ? Я пытался сам
       найти информацию , нашел информацию
       о конкатенации строк и это меня
       запутало . Результат ведь должен
       получиться bc , а получилась вообще
       цифра ?
3. Третий пример вообще не понятен .
       Подскажите пожалуйста почему выводит
       именно такой результат , или скиньте
       какой нибудь источник где это можно
       прочитать.

Заранее Спасибо

Comment: Я не знаю, что конкретно мне нужно найти для ответа на свой вопрос. Я пытался найти ответ, когда смотрел информацию по типу Char, но там не нашел того что мне нужно.

Comment: @Drylozav, а Вы бы учебник сначала, хоть по диагонали, прочли. 

Наверняка там есть раздел про преобразования типов.

Answer (score 4):

Про вызов перегруженных методов (кажется это так называется, когда у одноименных методов аргументы разных типов (в т.ч. разное количество аргументов)) Вам уже рассказали. А вот про их типы:

В первом случае операнд это константа типа **`char`** - она и печатается.

Насколько помню Java, для **`char`** специфическая операция **`+`** не определена,  т.е. в этом случае **`char`** переводится в **`int`** и тут складываются *коды* 'b' и 'c'. Результат, естественно типа **`int`** (он и печатается).

В третьем же случае, аналогично второму, получается результат типа **`int`**, который принудительно приводится (текст *(char)* в скобочках) к типу **`char`**.

Если посмотрите таблицу кодов ASCII, то 'a' + 4 это 0x61 + 4 == 0x65 т.е. 'e'.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ . (По совету выше) Я нашел методы PrintStream.println(char x) , PrintStream.println(int x) , но там про суммирование ничего не сказало . Меня собственно интересует , где можно прочитать про такие операции со строками, т.к. я гуглил , но похожего на мой примера не нашел .

Comment: @Drylozav, просто символы и строки это, можно так сказать, разные типы в Java. 

Хотя строки и состоят из символов, но они отличаются по методам работы в Java от массивов символов, в общем, особо выделены. IMHO класс String finalized, т.е. от него наследоваться нельзя.

Прочитать можно, например в "Философия Java" Б. Эккеля. Думаю и в других книжках тоже это есть.

Answer (score 2):

В первом и третьем случае вызвыается метод `PrintStream.println(char x)`, который `Prints a character. The character is translated into one or more bytes according to the platform's default character encoding`. То есть, печатается символ в кодировке по умолчанию.

Во втором случае вызывается метод `PrintStream.println(int x)`, который печатает число в десятичном формате.

А `a, b, c` у вас в программе в кавычках, так что это не переменные, а числа.

Comment: Скажите, а почему тогда в первом случае вывелась буква, а во втором цифра? Где можно об этом прочитать? И скажите, а почему это числа? Ведь я нигде не указывал их тип и не инициализировал их?

Comment: Я же написал - вызываются разные методы, с разной семантикой. Обратите внимание на тип параметра - методы различаются не только по названию, но и по типам параметров. Тип фактического параметра вы указали неявно - просто 'b' имеет тип char, а сумма чисел типов int и char - тип int. Это написано в любом учебнике по Яве.

Comment: А по какому правилу определяется , что печатать на экран ? В каких случая , какой метод будет вызван ?

Comment: Учли подан параметр типа char, вызывается PrintStream.println(char x), если типа int, то  PrintStream.println(int x).

Comment: То есть это выражение 'b' + 'c' , компилятор принимает как число (int) из за того, что тут присутствует арифметическое дейстивие ?

Comment: Да. Но если бы хоть одно слагаемое было типа float, то результат был бы тоже float. А если складывать строки, получим строку. Операции, как и методы, зависят от типов параметров.