# Почему метод print выдает результат 183?

Tags: java

```java
public class LogicOperations {
    
    public static void main (String[] args) {
        
        String greeting = "Hello";
        
        char first = greeting.charAt(0); //first symbol - 'H'
        char last = greeting.charAt(4); //last symbol - 'o'
        
        System.out.println(first + last); // 183?
        System.out.print(first); // 'H'
    }
}
```

Comment: А какое числовое представление символов **H** и **o**? И какова сумма этих чисел?

Comment: Код `H` - 72, код `o` - 111. См. [таблица ASCII](http://www.asciitable.com) А так у вас происходит сложение `char` и чтобы избежать возможного переполнения. `char` расширяется до `int`

Comment: Вообще нашел похожий вопрос: [ссылка](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/216081/Преобразрвание-типа-char-в-методе-system-out-println)

Comment: Спасибо за разъяснение.